# Pyspark user_agent parsing

Tags: pyspark

I am new with PySpark, ask advice. I' am using https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/  for PySpark dataframe

I  would  like to apply user_agents library for PySpark dataframe column (user_agent).
user_agent record:  user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SM-T580) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Safari/537.36

My code:

```
from user_agents import parse 

df = df.withColumn("browser", parse((df.user_agent.cast("string"))))
```

The error:

> ```
>  TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'
> ```

I did it in this way, but it takes too much time ( how can I optimize it):

```
    from user_agents import parse
    vals_init = [("", "", "","","")]
    columns = ['browser', 'os', 'device-brand','device-family',   
    'device-model' ]
    df1 = spark.createDataFrame(vals_init, columns)
    for row in df.rdd.collect():
    #    str(row.user_agent)
    #    user_agent = parse(str(row.user_agent))
       print(user_agent.browser[0])  #browser
       print(user_agent.os[0])  #OS
       print(user_agent.device.family)  # returns 'iPhone'
       print(user_agent.device.brand) # returns 'Apple'
       print(user_agent.device.model) # returns 'iPhone'
       vals = [(user_agent.browser[0],  
       user_agent.os[0],user_agent.device.family,
       user_agent.device.family,user_agent.device.brand,
       user_agent.device.model)]

       newRow =       
       spark.createDataFrame([(user_agent.browser[0],user_agent.os[0],                                           
       user_agent.device.family,user_agent.device.brand,
       user_agent.device.model)], columns)
       df1 = df1.union(newRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not an Open Source tool, when it comes to analyzing User-Agent (or more generally HTTP requests), WURFL is the de-facto standard tool used by the big guys (Akamai, AWS, Google,...) who requires more properties and fine-grained analysis of their HTTP traffic.

[Here is a blog post that explains how WURFL and PySpark can be integrated](https://www.scientiamobile.com/wurfl-microservice-pyspark-device-detection-tutorial/). It would be awesome if the author could reference this in the article.

Disclosure: I'm the WURFL inventor